# Truffle migrate --reset without loosing data

Tags: migration, blockchain, solidity, ganache

I am developing a smart contract using solidity. Every time I edit the contract and want to prove it I run `truffle migrate --reset`.

By doing so, I lose all the data that I had saved in the contract.

I wonder if there is any way to migrate the contract while preserving the data, as it is done with traditional databases, since only by `truffle migrate` the contract is not migrated, it is only recompiled.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: Currently not possible using Truffle. But if you know what you're doing, you could keep the storage with more low-level approach.**

---

By running `truffle migrate` you are usually running a javascript code that deploys the Solidity contract using the standard `CREATE` EVM opcode. So every time you're running `truffle migrate`, Truffle deploys the contract to a new address that has empty storage slots.

Even though it's possible to redeploy a smart contract to an already used address using `CREATE2` opcode (and to keep the original storage data), Truffle currently doesn't support this option.

*Note: The `--reset` option only runs all migrations from the beginning in case of previous failure, but has no effect on the storage or the contract address.*

---

You could achieve this goal (keeping the storage) by setting the (contract deployment) transaction data to an instruction to deploy to an address that already contains a self-destruct contract. But it's much more low-level approach than Truffle currently allows. If you want to learn more about this technique, these articles would be a good start:

- https://blog.ricmoo.com/wisps-the-magical-world-of-create2-5c2177027604
- https://medium.com/@jason.carver/defend-against-wild-magic-in-the-next-ethereum-upgrade-b008247839d2